# Does anything useful happen during the KDE Plasma5 splash screen load delay? It seems to just waste time

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5, kde5

As far as I can tell the startup splashscreen after logging in on Kubuntu with Plasma5 seems to be a pointless busy loop that locks up the user interface for several seconds while nothing is achieved and everyone would be better off disabling it.

- Is this the case? Or am I missing something?
- What could the possible justification for such
  a pointless delay be?

Background: I was trying to tweak my startup/login backgrounds on my Kubuntu install from the hideous default image and ended up finding [this thread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=126760).

Running the command

```
kcmshell5 splashscreen
```

Allows you to select "None" as the splash screen theme.

Since doing so my desktop starts almost instantly without the silly progress bar and painfully slow to fade out splash screen. Seriously, I really like the new look KDE desktop it's great work, but this fake delay just seems mad, someone should read [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/pros-cons-of-splash-screen-with-articifial-loading-delay).

Comment: You might be able to see what's going on with strace, though I agree it seems like nothing

Comment: I guess it's to let slower machines load any startup applications and _then_ appear to be ready to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "useful". It's there so that you don't have to see the different parts of Plasma (e.g. panel, desktop, icons, etc) loading one at a time if your system is slow. There is no problem with turning it off if your system is fast enough that everything appears instantly, or if you don't care that things appear one-at-a-time.

Source: am a KDE developer. :)

Comment: Thanks for following up this old question I'd forgotten about, sorry it's a bit snarky - I must have posted in the morning without having a coffee first. I am still using KDE everywhere, and have been disabling the splash screen for the intervening 3 years with no issues. As you point out I notice that sometimes elements appear before others but I'd definitely rather see that happening than a splash that prevents you doing anything at all. Thanks also for your work on KDE, it's definitely the best DE.